# EditText is missing in eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse

in my Android guide the instructor chooses to add EditText field into the Graphical Layout. In the video i can see that it's listed under "From Widgets" but i don't see EditText option in the list of widgets in my eclipse.

i succeeded in adding the EditText manually into the XML with the following code:

```
<EditText android:id="@+id/edit_message"
    android:layout_weight="1000"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="bl" />
```

but i don't understand why i add it from Graphical Layout mode.

does any one know what the problem is?
I added two images the first present the instructor eclipse and the second my eclipse so you can see that it's missing.

[image: This is what is missing in my eclipse]
[image: This is my eclipse]

Comment: Please use Android Studio for better performance

Comment: Android Studio is extremely slow